# Show LMI $F(x)\succ0$ is feasible if and only if the LMI $F(x) \succeq I_{n \times n}$ is feasible

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, linear-matrix-inequality

> Let $F : V \to \Bbb S^{n\times n}$ be a linear map, where $V$ is a vector space and and $S^{n\times n}$ is the set of $n \times n$ symmetric matrices. Prove that the LMI $F(x) \succ 0$ is feasible if and only if the LMI $F(x) \succeq I_{n \times n}$ is feasible.

I kind know I show use eigenvalue of matrix $F(x)$ to find

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    F_1(x) &  &  \\
     & F_2(x) &  \\
     &  & F_3(x) \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

but got stuck here. Please Help!

Comment: Sorry, edited the question, it meant to be F

Answer (score 1):

"If" should be easy. 
For "only if", note that the strict inequality $F(x)\succ0$ implies the existence of some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $F(x)\succeq\varepsilon I_{n\times n}$.
Now, you only need to use linearity of $F$ to finish the proof. Can you take it from here?

Comment: not the strictness but continuous dependence on $x$ makes it possible to squeeze an epsilon there